# Using json.dumps(string) to dump a string

Tags: python, json

I want to put string into json.dumps()

```
string = "{data}"

print json.dumps(string)
```

And I get:

`"{data}"` instead of: `{data}`

How I can get this string without quotes?

Method `replace`:

```
json.dumps(string.replace('"', '')
```

or `strip`:

```
json.dumps(string.strip('"')
```

Does not work.

Answer (score 14):

You don't dump *a* string but *to a* string.

```
d = {"foo": "bar"}
j = json.dumps(d)
print(j)
```

Output:

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

It makes no sense to use a string as the argument of [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) which is expecting a dictionary or a list/tuple as the argument.

> Serialize `obj` to a JSON formatted str using this conversion table.

Comment: you might want to print j instead of d

Comment: If I want the dictionary to convert to a string i might use json.dumps(). But if I already have a string that I can send it to the recipient without json.dumps? Before ensure that the recipient receives it correctly.

Comment: If the content of the string is valid JSON you can send it to somebody who expects JSON. But note that `{data}` is *not* valid JSON. Check it at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The question is ambiguous.But as far as i understand after using json.dumps he is getting a string and wants to change it into a dict..

Comment: IMHO it would be clearer if you wrote your output like this: `'{"foo": "bar"}'`, the way @Ajay is doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [17]: d = {"foo": "bar"}

In [18]: j = json.dumps(d)

In [19]: j
Out[19]: '{"foo": "bar"}'
```

Now if you need your dictionary back instead of a string

```
In [37]: l=json.loads(j)

In [38]: l
Out[38]: {u'foo': u'bar'}
```

or  alternatively

```
In [20]: import ast
In [22]: k=ast.literal_eval(j)

In [23]: k
Out[23]: {'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: What about [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)?

Comment: by {data} OP means a dict i guess

Comment: I still don't understand why you propose to use `ast`. Why?

Comment: "{data}" instead of: {data}
he asked his desired output to be like this